# How can I access the page data context inside a UWP control data template?

Tags: uwp, binding, datacontext

I currently have a page view model which contains an information view model. The information view model in initialise in the page view model correctly and I can bind the objects to the controls in the information view model as expected. However, I have an issue when the UWP app enters edit mode.
I toggle the visibility of some controls and their parts in the information view model based on the global edit state.

I have created a dependency property called IsEditing which is a boolean and it correctly passes the value from the page view model to the information view model.

The IsEditing property is not being honored inside data templates. For example,

```
<toolkitControls:DataGrid>
   <toolkitControls:DataGrid.Columns>
      <toolkitControls:DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="MyDataGrid" Header="AGE">
                                    <toolkitControls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock
                                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                    Foreground="{StaticResource Blue}"
                                                    Style="{StaticResource MyTextBlockStyle}"
                                                    Text="{Binding User.Age}"
                                                    Visibility="{Binding Path=IsEditing, ElementName=Page, Converter={StaticResource CollapseConverter}}" />
```

Note: the page has the name  `x:Name="Page"`

I have also tried the following bindings which are also not working:

```
Visibility="{Binding Path=DataContext.IsEditing, ElementName=Page, Converter={StaticResource CollapseConverter}}"
```

```
Visibility="{Binding Path=DataContext.IsEditing, ElementName=MyDataGrid, Converter={StaticResource CollapseConverter}}"
```

Has anyone else managed to get this working in their UWP app?

Comment: How and where is `IsEditing` defined?

Comment: I'm afraid you have not implement notifypropertychange interface  for IsEditing property, could you share more detail for IsEditing property?